# Adobe Illustrator - File Grouping

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator

Is there a way to open multiple AI files (say 3 individual files) and somehow save in a way that I can open the same 3 files simultaneously in the future? I always want the multiple files to open together.

Situation:
We design products with AI. A single product may have multiple versions. The designer typically creates 1 AI file, then puts all versions of the product in the single file. I need them to put each version in a separate file for an integration project, but this creates more work for them.

The solution I'm looking for would allow them to open all the relevant AI file and somehow same them all as a group. Next time, they open the group and all AI files open together.

Thank you

Comment: A 'file grouping' as in a folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group files and tag files in Adobe Bridge, but to open them at the same time you either have to select them all right click and hit open, or have them in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just open notepad, save it in any name as "open" with extension of ".bat" as it will look as "open.bat". Now save in that directory in which files are placed.

Now type
start your_file_name_1.ai
start your_file_name_2.ai
start your_file_name_3.ai

{start[space][file name with extension]}Write as much as you like. And save it. And after saving the file, these files will simultaneously open one after another.

Hop this works.